# How to change the code using lambda expression?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

I'm study about c++ using lambda expression.
I'm just tried change the code that already coded using for or while, then i have the question about lambda.

I'm just change the code using lambda or for_each (c++11). How to change?

Here is a code that want to change.

```
std::string PointToString(void* p_pData)
{
    char* p = (char*)p_pData;

    int iLength = 0;
    std::memcpy(&iLength, p, sizeof(int));
    p += sizeof(int);

    std::string sRet;
    std::array<char, 3> szB;
    sRet.append("0x");

    for ( int i = 0; i < iLength; i++ )
    {
        sprintf(szB.data(), "%02X", (unsigned char)*(p++));
        sRet.append(szB.data());
    }

    return sRet;
}
```

This code just convert a memory value to hex code.
That function called like this.

```
char szB[15] = {0x0b, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xc7, 0xd1, 0xb1, 0xdb, 0xc0, 0xd4, 0xb4, 0xcf, 0xb4, 0xd9, 0x2e};

void* p = nullptr;

p = (void*)szB;

sRet = PointToString(p);
```

The Result may be 0x0B000000C7D1.....

I want to try lambda in PointToString function. How can I change that function?

Comment: your example doesn't seem to match up - your code reads a 2-byte length, and then reads that many more bytes.  But your example result didn't read the length. And `0x0B` is `11`, so even if it did then your input is 2 bytes too long.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you could write:

```
std::for_each(p, p + iLength, [&](unsigned char ch)
{
    sprintf(szB.data(), "%02X", ch);
    sRet.append(szB.data());
});
```

The `&` means that you will operate on `szB` and `sRet` by reference, instead of operating on copies of them.

IMHO it's not a significant improvement over your original code though.